# Simplest way to use updated version of Packer?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

What is the easiest way (when using VSTS) to use the latest version of Packer?

I keep getting this error when trying to use the "Build Immutable Image (Preview)" build step. I understand that I could install my own agent and in that have the correct Packer version... But it would be a lot better if there is an easier way - using hosted agents.

`Packer validate command failed. This could happen if task does not support packer version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Packer doesn’t need to be installed on the build agent, you just need to add it to the path environment before Build immutable image task, you can add packer.exe to source control and map to build agent or download it during the build time (e.g. through Node.js, PowerShell).

For example (add it to source control: tools folder):

1. Add PowerShell task (Type: Inline Script)
2. Arguments: -sd $(build.sourcesdirectory)

Script:

```
param(
[string]$sd
)
$tools= "$sd\tools";
Write-Host $tools
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]${env:PATH};${tools}";
```

On the other hand, there is the source code: [PackerBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PackerBuild)

Comment: Thanks for this, but it would be even simpler if the agent had the latest version of Packer available :-)